# jcarousel not appearing in Chrome, Safari, Opera

Tags: php, javascript, cross-browser

here is the problematic page:http://sideradesign.com/eco-art/gallery/
The gallery displays in IE8 and Firefox, but not in Chrome, Opera or Safari.
Let me explain : first of all, I'm not an expert in javascript, I have just copied a wordpress plugin code into the functions.php file and hacked away at it until it worked in Firefox.
The original plugin is http://noscope.com/journal/2009/03/c...-for-wordpress

I noticed that in Chrome, there are 2 divs that don't get assigned the same classes as they do in Firefox, and the UL that contains the images is empty. So apparently the javascript is being executed correctly.
these 2 divs have no class in Chrome:

```
<div class="jcarousel-container jcarousel-container-horizontal" style="display: block;">
<div class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal">
```

I hope someone can help

thanks
Paul

Comment: Unfortunately, pasting 300 lines of badly formatted code isn't the best way to get answers to your problems at Stack Overflow.

Comment: sorry about that, so how can I find the bad code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see: [jCarousel not showing next button correctly in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433507/jcarousel-not-showing-next-button-correctly-in-safari)

the plugin is no longer maintained, so doesnt work correctly newer versions of Safari..
there is an easy fix though :

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/8f30314e21bbaa6f