# jCarousel not showing next button correctly in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

Im having a little problem with jCarousel ( http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ ).

Everything works fine in Firefox and IE, however in Safari the carousel displays but the next button is inactive when there are actually more elements. Firefox and IE show the next button as active.

Is there a common fix for this or a known bug in jCarosuel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Oops, found the solution.
http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/8f30314e21bbaa6f

Nice to know the author doesn't upkeep the code.